# href com target blank em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma imagem dentro de uma **div.facebook** que recebe o `clike` do mouse e redireciona para uma página externa:

```
$("div.facebook img").click(function() {
     $(location).attr('href','http://www.facebook.com');
 });
```

Acontece que gostaria que abrisse em outra janela.

Tentei várias opções, dentre elas:

```
$("div.facebook img").click(function() {
     $(location).attr('href','http://www.facebook.com');              
                .attr('target','_blank')
 });
```

Mas não deu certo.

O que pode ser feito nesse caso para continuar com **jQuery**?

Answer (score 0):

Cara sua pergunta trouxe a tona uma coisa que não sabia, a tag Html **target** foi descontinuada pela `w3c` [saiba mais aqui](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/present/frames.html#adef-target). Então agora é indicado utilizar a tag **rel** com o valor **external** assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").attr("href", "http://www.facebook.com");
    $("a[rel=external]").click(function() {
        if (!this.oldHref) {
            this.oldHref = this.href;
            this.href = "";
        }
        window.open(this.oldHref);
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<a rel="external">Aperte</a>
```

Comment: Não deu certo. O redirecionamento ocorre. Mas NÃO com target blank

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: será que <img rel="external" src='' /> funciona? Porque se funcionar, basta colocar padrão o normal href